# File Upload With Progress

Tags: php

I know this has been discussed a number of times, but the problem I'm having at the moment is finding a solution that is easy to work with and does not require much hacking around.

I want to be able to upload a file, and report on its progress. I've been playing with SWFUpload, and it seems like a bit to much messing around for my liking. Integrating it with code igniter just seems like it's going to cause headaches.

I want a visual progress indicator of some sort to show the user their upload hasn't stagnated. Even if it was just a spinner saying "Uploading. Do not close this window until upload is complete." that would be enough for me.

Security is the most important. Using something like SWFUpload is going to require passing variables to the upload form such as the user ID and other information I'd rather not give snooping noses the opportunity to sniff.

Any possible solutions. Help is much appreciated.

Comment: [Google is your friend](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=codeigniter+file+upload+progress).

Comment: @Alex I've been through most of those. Most discuss SWFUploader at some point. I've managed to find this a moment ago though via a friend http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/how-to-upload-files-with-codeigniter-and-ajax/

Comment: Using just a spinner gif is trivial, just place it and remove it when the script ends. Anyway, I second @Alex suggestion of using uplodify, it's nice and reliable

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at HTML5 FormData and XMLHttpRequest 2 which allow you watch the progress directly in javascript.

Comment: HTML is pretty "wide spread", all modern browsers support it. I think HTML even has it's own Wikipedia article now!

Answer (score 0):

You must customize the tool to meet your requirement , especially when its open source .

> Security is the most important. Using something like SWFUpload is
>   going to require passing variables to the upload form such as the user
>   ID and other information I'd rather not give snooping noses the
>   opportunity to sniff.

Why you need to pass user ID ? i think its HTTP matter not SWFUpload,so you can make it secure .
Look here : http://demo.swfupload.org/Documentation/

Answer (score 0):

I'm actually on the hunt for the same thing. A few of the options I have encountered so far are:

- http://www.uploadify.com
- http://valums.com/ajax-upload/ (Which is now headed off by Ben Colon here - github dot com / bencolon / file-uploader )

I haven't used any of those solutions because I'm not quite sure how to customize them for my application. But it looks like so far in my research, those are links that keep popping up.